# Flutter FutureBuilder returns a K:V object on initial child().get() but only V remains on state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-futurebuilder

This is a behavior I'm not understanding but am sure I've got something wrong. Components: Flutter, Realtime Database, FutureBuilder. Modified code:

```
[FormView class omitted but extends StatefulWidget]

class _FormViewState extends State<FormView> {
  final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  getDataSnapshot() async {
    try {
      final value = await dbRef.child('child1').child('child2').child('datetimegroup').get();
      return value;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return FutureBuilder(
      future: getDataSnapshot(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          context.go("/error/${snapshot.error}");
        }
        else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          ... 
          case ConnectionState.done:
              print(snapshot.data.value);
              CUSTOMDATACLASS dataValue = CUSTOMDATACLASS.fromJson(snapshot.data.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
          break;
          ...
```

The data then populates a readonly form (it is to view the inputs from previously entered forms).

**Issue**

On page load, the form is displayed completely empty, with no errors. On hot reload (or state change), the form fields are filled in. No errors on page or in console.

Printing the data snapshot to the console shows 2 different formats. The format of the data on the initial get() operation (on initial `connectionState.done`) is (as json) `{key: {k:v pairs}}`. Specifically, the key is the `'datetimegroup'` child from the `await dbRef...` call. On hot reload (or state change) the format drops the `'datetimegroup'` child and simply returns `{k:v pairs}`, which is the expected return format from the get() operation, anyway (as I understand it).

If I add the `datetimegroup` as a key, then the form populates on initial page load but I get a subsequent error. That change is from: `CUSTOMDATACLASS dataValue = CUSTOMDATACLASS.fromJson(snapshot.data.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);`
to `CUSTOMDATACLASS dataValue = CUSTOMDATACLASS.fromJson(snapshot.data.value['datetimegroup'] as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);`

But of course then hot reload or page state changes result in an (expected) error (because the key is gone):

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? Why would the value include the last child as a key but then change?

*note: the CUSTOMDATACLASS is just a data model which provides toJson() / fromJson() functions for the data to make the form<->database translation a little easier. *